# The command "./vendor/bin/sail up" returns "unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q" in a Laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker

I followed two beginner tutorials explaining how to set up a Laravel project in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-linux

https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-run-laravel-in-a-docker-container-using-laravel-sail.aspx

There, the following code is provided (example from the first tutorial):

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

When trying to use the command `./vendor/bin/sail up` in a Laravel, I receive an error `unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q`, followed by the docker help instructions. This arises even though I did not even use the -q flag.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The -q flaq is used by the docker-compose command in the sail file in the folder `./vendor/bin`.

The problem arises because the package docker-compose is not installed. It can be installed by the following command:

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```

Comment: I get an error... E: Unable to locate package docker-compose