# './vendor/bin/sail/up' returns 'unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q' in a Laravel project with docker-compose installed

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I followed this guide to set up Sail on a Laravel project:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail

The guide says to run the following commands inside your Laravel project:

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev
php artisan sail:install
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

When I run the last command to start Sail, `./vendor/bin/sail up` instead of starting Sail I get an error that says 'unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q' and then returns the Docker help commands.

I checked online and an answer to this problem ([The command "./vendor/bin/sail up" returns "unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q" in a Laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834264/the-command-vendor-bin-sail-up-returns-unknown-shorthand-flag-q-in-q-i)) was to install docker-compose but I do have it installed. Its version is 1.22.0. I'm using a macOS and Laravel 9 because my work asked me for that version instead of 10.

Comment: @JasonOlson this link is in the question.

Comment: Please type `docker-compose -v` in a terminal, click on **Edit** and copy paste the output of the command in the question.

Comment: @A.L output is `docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f`

Comment: @santiago and if you run `docker compose version` (without the `-`)? I do think you do not have the latest version, it is 2.x, you have 1.x